# How to add a field in entity in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I try to add a cahmps in entity. I have this code:

```
/**
* @var integer $colorevent
* @ORM\Column(name="colorevent", type="integer")
*/
private $colorevent;

/**
* Get colorevent
* @return integer 
*/ 
public function getColorevent()
{
    return $this->colorevent;
}

/**
* Set colorevent
* @return integer 
*/
public function setColorevent($colorevent)
{
    return $this->colorevent = $colorevent ;
}
```

I run these commands:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

which renders this message:

> Nothing to update yopur database is already in sync with the current
>   entity metadata

How do I add a field in entity?

Answer (score 2):

How did you generated the entity class in the first time?

It the entity file was generated via `doctrine:generate:entities` then what you need to do is:

1. update the `Resources/config/doctrine/XXXXXXXXX` where xxxx is the entity name.
2. run `app/console doctrine:generate:entity`. This will regenerate the php entity file, and the private property, getter and setter.
3. run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update` and update the DB

There may be some changes depending of the format you are using (I'm using yml) but the bottom line is that the `doctrine:schema:update` needs to find changes between the current and the cached (metadata) entity objects.

Comment: I gave this a try, but I too couldn't get this to work.  Essentially it just doesn't pick up the changes done to the Entity.  (eg: change a column in the db to allow nullable fields, still renders a "nothing has changed" screen)

Answer (score 1):

Each entity must have the `Entity` annotation

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MyEntity
{
    // some code
}
```

I would also suggest using the console tools provided to create the entities.

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

For more information please read the official book ([Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html), [Propel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/propel.html)).

Comment: Yes I try but it's the same probleme

Answer (score 0):

If you're using yaml or annotations as described in the other two answers you can use the doctrine command. However the command must contain the entity name:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeMyBundle:Customer
```